# AWS Lambda: Jackson Annotations ignored when creating response in hosted version

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jackson, aws-lambda

Part of my response object for my Lambda function is an object containing 3 arrays. For any given instance of the function, only one of them will have any content. I have used the @JsonInclude annotation (I have tried using it at the class level, and above the properties or the getters) to tell the ObjectMapper to ignore the empty arrays when creating the response. This works find on my local version the response only contains one array with data, but when I deploy it to my actual AWS Lambda function the annotations are ignored and the response contains 3 arrays, 2 of which are empty. Code is below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

public class PcIODataSetString {

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
    private EventDef[] ttEventDefs;
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
    private EventTag[] ttEventTags;
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
    private EventObj[] ttEventObjs;

    //getters and setters
}
```

From what I've read I'm thinking it may be a version problem, since I'm using jackson-annotations-2.6.0 and maybe AWS uses a version 1.x for the Lambda functions? Is there any way to force AWS to use the same version of jackson? The 2.6.0 jackson jar is present in the AWS SDK library which is bundled in my jar.

Answer (score 0):

As you indicate the AWS Java Lambda must be doing some deserialization of the objects passed into your handle and I would agree that you're correct in that the versions may collide.

How hard would it be for you to switch to a different JSON serializer?  I've used [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) quite a bit and in the newer versions the default is to not include null fields.

To serialize an object to JSON it's a simple:

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(yourObject);
```

From JSON it is something like:

```
YourObject yourObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString);
```

Again, this may be a total pain for you to convert to a different serializer but it would avoid any dependencies on the Jackson library versions.